# Why do I get a full table scan in one case, but not the other?

Tags: mysql, datetime, indexing, query-optimization, mysql-5.7

EDIT: It is on mysql version 5.5.62-38.14-log, that I have the problem, BTW, although the examples were run on 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 on my local machine. I have changed the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` in my queries to `TIMESTAMP()`, but no change.

Can somebody help see the light, please? I have a relatively simple table:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `game_instance` (
    ->   `game_instance_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `game_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->   `currency_code` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `start_datetime` timestamp,
    ->   `status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'COMING, NMB = No More Bets, RESOLVED, TB= Taking Bets',
    ->   `created_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ->   `end_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `external_ref` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `game_room_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`game_instance_id`,`start_datetime`),
    ->   KEY `GI_IDX4` (`external_ref`),
    ->   KEY `GI_IDX5` (`game_id`,`status`),
    ->   KEY `game_instance_status` (`status`),
    ->   KEY `game_instance_end_datetime` (`end_datetime`),
    ->   KEY `game_instance_start_datetime` (`start_datetime`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=118386942 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)

mysql> explain select * from game_instance where start_datetime >= unix_timestamp(CONCAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY), ' ', '00:00:00'));
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | partitions | type | possible_keys                | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | game_instance | NULL       | ALL  | game_instance_start_datetime | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

I have an index on `start_datetime`, but I still get a full table scan, according to `explain`.

However:

```
mysql> create table ex1(
    -> id bigint(20),
    -> start_datetime timestamp,
    -> primary key (id,start_datetime),
    -> key (start_datetime)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> explain select * from ex1 where start_datetime>=unix_timestamp(CONCAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY), ' ', '00:00:00'));
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+----------------+----------------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys  | key            | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+----------------+----------------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ex1   | NULL       | index | start_datetime | start_datetime | 4       | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+----------------+----------------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
1 row in set, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

The warnings are:

```
mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect datetime value: '1563663600' for column 'start_datetime' at row 1                                                                                                                                                        |
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect datetime value: '1563663600' for column 'start_datetime' at row 1                                                                                                                                                        |
| Note    | 1003 | /* select#1 */ select `ex`.`ex1`.`id` AS `id`,`ex`.`ex1`.`start_datetime` AS `start_datetime` from `ex`.`ex1` where (`ex`.`ex1`.`start_datetime` >= <cache>(unix_timestamp(concat((curdate() - interval 30 day),' ','00:00:00')))) |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This seems to suggest that `start_datetime` is silently converted in the background, which would explain why the index is not used, but then why does it not happen in both queries? (And as a corollary, how do I convert my date string to whatever the MySQL TIMESTAMP is?)

---

EDIT 2:

I've run optimize on the table, as suggested in comments (I haven't run the analyze, since it seems to have done that already):

```
mysql> optimize table game_instance;
+-----------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                 | Op       | Msg_type | Msg_text                                                          |
+-----------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| gameiom.game_instance | optimize | note     | Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead |
| gameiom.game_instance | optimize | status   | OK                                                                |
+-----------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (21 min 31.80 sec)
```

However, it made no difference:

```
mysql> explain select * from game_instance 
  where start_datetime >= timestamp(CONCAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY), ' ', '00:00:00')) and 
  start_datetime <= timestamp(CONCAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), ' ', '23:59:59'));
+----+-------------+---------------+------+------------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys                | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+------------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | game_instance | ALL  | game_instance_start_datetime | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 19065747 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+------------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is a real problem, since the table is 19m rows (not 11m as I said earlier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the query planner makes decisions about whether to scan the whole table or use the index based on statistics about the number and distribution of values in the index. Sometimes it guesses that a full table scan will take less CPU and IO resources than a table lookup.

When tables have small numbers of rows, the query planner's choices often don't match intuition. Make sure you have a few thousand rows at least, before you spend a lot of time trying to make sense of `EXPLAIN` output.

Also, the query planner gets better at its job with each MySQL release.

Do `OPTIMIZE TABLE game_instance` to clean up your table, especially if you have inserted many rows.

Then do `ANALYZE TABLE game_instance` to recompute the statistics used by the query planner.

By the way,

```
  where start_datetime>=unix_timestamp(CONCAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY), ' ', '00:00:00'));
```

is precisely the same as

```
  where start_datetime >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

MySQL knows how to use the results of date computations directly in TIMESTAMP filters, and UNIX_TIMESTAMP() yields integers, not TIMESTAMPs.

About your invalid timestamp warning, may I suggest you ask another question? Please include your time zone setting in the question.

Comment: OK, I'm running analyse table on the prod database atm - that table has >11m rows, so it is still ongoing; then I'll see how it goes. It makes sense that this should help, I think, since I created the index today, when the table was already big. As for the warnings, it seems using timestamp() made them go away, but what you say is that it could be much simpler, so I'll change that. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by O. Jones was correct, but let me just add some notes about what I did to find out. What I was seeing was this, which I couldn't understand:

```
mysql> explain extended
select * from game_instance
where
  start_datetime >= timestamp(CONCAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY), ' ', '00:00:00')) and
  start_datetime <= timestamp(CONCAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), ' ', '23:59:59'));
+----+-------------+---------------+------+------------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys                | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+------------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | game_instance | ALL  | game_instance_start_datetime | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 18741262 |    50.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+------------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

So, I found that you can force MySQL to use an index, which gave me:

```
mysql> explain extended select * from game_instance force index (game_instance_start_datetime) where start_datetime >= timestamp(CONCAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY), ' ', '00:00:00')) and start_datetime <= timestamp(CONCAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), ' ', '23:59:59'));
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type  | possible_keys                | key                          | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | game_instance | range | game_instance_start_datetime | game_instance_start_datetime | 4       | NULL | 9391936 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

IOW, using the index selects about half of all the rows in the table, and now the `filtered` column makes sense: it is the percentage of rows that are thrown away because they don't match the criteria, which is why MySQL doesn't use the index: it is less efficient because you'd alternate between reading the index and seeking addresses in the table.